# How to not send hotkey text to open editor

Tags: autohotkey

I use this hotkey to close the current Window :

```
:*:xx::
    Send, {Alt Down}{Sleep 100}{f4 Down}{Alt Up}{f4 Up}
    return  ;
```

How can the script be amended so that the characters `xx` are not sent to display but are still registered by autohotkeys ? In other words if focus is within open editor do not display the `xx` characters but still fire the commands associated with the `xx` keys.

Comment: The easiest way is adding "Send, ^s" before the !{f4} command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it with a Hotstring but you would have have to use a Hotkey and check for a double key press. A regular key like x might not be the most useful as it will most likely always get in the way of your regular typing as you want to block the x being sent. An example with Ctrl:

```
~Ctrl::
KeyWait, Ctrl           ; wait for Ctrl to be released
KeyWait, Ctrl, D T0.2   ; and pressed again within 0.2 seconds
if ErrorLevel ; timed-out (only a single press)
    MsgBox single
else
    MsgBox double
return
```

The above code comes from here http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/23224-resolved-catch-a-double-press-click/#entry150299 and you will also find an example (no 4) on the KeyWait doc http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/KeyWait.htm